# About This Mac → Storage suggests more space in on the SSD than is actually being used

Tags: finder, ssd, dropbox

I've got a 480 GB SSD in a MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. I have recently reformatted the drive and clean installed the OS.

I have very limited programmes installed on this machine and all my files are managed by Dropbox, using their [smart sync feature](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/smart-sync), which stores all your files in the Dropbox cloud and downloads them locally as and when you need them.

What's strange is that although I've got a 480 GB SSD, and only using c. 25GB as confirmed by the total at the bottom of Finder (see attached screenshot), if I go to About this Mac → Storage, it says I've used about 210 GB, mostly all photos and movies.

Any idea why this would be?

[image: screenshot showing finder and about this mac storage]